# Azure ServiceBus - Moving messages from Poison to Dead Letter Queue

Tags: azureservicebus

I am currently working with Azure Service Bus, from what I understand:

- A message that has exceeded the maximum number of delivery attempts is moved to the poison queue.
- Moving a message to the dead letter queue is a manual operation.

If I don't have any specific requirement, Is it  a good practice to move messages from poison to dead letter queue (using the [EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.enabledeadletteringonmessageexpiration.aspx) option) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Messages land in the Poison and Dead Letter queue for very different reasons.

Messages that have exceeded the maximum number of retry attempts are sent to the Poison Queue. Messages can land in the Poison Queue for lots of reasons including errors within the message itself. Here the messages will stay until manually put back into a queue or until they expire.

Dead Letters are messages that are sent to a queue and have a maximum lifetime associated with them. Messages land in the Dead Letter Queue because they have gone undelivered for a certain amount of time. There may not be anything wrong with these messages, they have just gone undelivered and have been put aside.

That being said, it is probably not good practice to move messages from the Poison queue to the Dead Letter queue because moving messages to the Dead Letter queue is not usually a manual operation.

Comment: @Thomas glad I could help!